# Platform dependant Rakefile

Tags: cygwin, rake, jetty, rakefile

I'm writing a Rakefile that, at some point, starts Jetty. The Rakefile should be platform independant so I can use it in my windows and my mac. To start jetty there are two scripts provided: jetty.sh and jetty-cygwin.sh depending on the system you are on.

In a bash script I know that there is a OSTYPE that I can use to determine if i'm under win or under mac but it is unavailable under ENV in ruby. Is there any way of doing something similar in a Rakefile?

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try `ENV['OS']`? With Windows I get `"Windows_NT"` - sorry I can't test it for Mac.

There is also the constant `RUBY_PLATFORM` ( I get `"i386-mingw32"`) - perhaps you can use 
that.

---

Another idea, if the constants don't work:

The command `ver` is defined in windows and returns the windows version. What happens when you call it on the Mac? You could try something like:

```
case %x{ver}
  when /Microsoft Windows/
    puts "I'm running Windows"
  when /Mac/
    puts "I'm running on a Mac"
  else
    puts "Unknown?"
end
```

Replace the `/Mac/` with the result you have (even if it is an error message - if you get the error, it's not Windows ;) ).

Comment: Yep. I finished up comparing the output of commands in the three environments